# Как переделать категориальный датасет в бинарный?

Tags: python, pandas, кодировка, numpy, dataset

[image: Заданный датасет]

```
Мне нужно шкалировать датасет, который имеет данные в 3 категории (обозначены через 0, 1, 2) и -1(данные отсутствуют).
Мне надо эти данные прошкалировать и, чтоб получилось следующее:
```

**0 |—> (1,0,0)**

**1 |—> (0,1,0)**

**2 |—> (0,0,1)**

**-1 |—> (0,0,0)**

```
 Как это можно реализовать в Python? Надо ли применять OneHotEncoding?
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!:)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну да, с виду это что-то типа OHE. А с какой целью вы это делаете? Я почему спрашиваю - возможно, вам это и не нужно вовсе. Ну если конечно вам не нужно обязательно линейную регрессию использовать и т.д. Ансамбли, например, решающие деревья, могут и без такого преобразования прекрасно работать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я преобразовываю данные для последующего нахождения бикластеров